# Why does calculation of matrix percentages in r lead to a mistake in one of the values?

Tags: matrix, percentage

I have to calculate percentage of living and dead plants in two different fields.

The matrix is:

`Alive <- matrix(c(3001, 151, 2488, 136),  ncol = 2, dimnames = list(c("Alive", "Dead"), c("Field_1", "Field_2")))`

To calculate percentage, I use the code:

`AlivePercent <- Alive/colSums(Alive) * 100`

But the output is false. To be more exact, it is correct for three cells, but not for the upper right cell “Field_2 Alive”. Manual calculation shows that the result here must be 94.82%. But the R-code line above results in only 78.93%.

I have already tried to convert the matrix into a data frame and use

`lapply(Alive, function(x) x/sum(x))`

It gives a good result. However, I do not want to do such transformations. I would like to work with simple matrices. So, maybe someone knows the reason of the mistake above and how to avoid it?

PS: I tested this code also on other matrices. And always the upper right cell results in a false value.